# How to get text from a EditText and display it in a field on a website? [Android/Java]

Tags: java, android, html, text

I'm using `getText()` to get text from a `Edittext`. Now by clicking on a button, this text should be put into a field on a website (for example google.com) and search after this text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JavaScript`.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('form-id').value='your-value';
```

This code will find your form with the `id="form-id"` attribute, and put the value `your-value` in it. You can call this just using `loadUrl();`.

For search, you can also press the search button using `JavaScript`.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('myButton-id').click();
```

An example implementation can be:

```
String searchValue = "You got this from your editText";
String callValue = "javascript:document.getElementById('form-id').value='" + searchValue + "'; document.getElementById('myButton-id').click();";
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
myWebView.loadUrl(callValue);
```

**EDIT**

This is the element ID for Google: gbqfq
[image: GBQFQ]

Comment: Ok, I guess that's what I'm looking for...ehm but is there something like `javascript:document.getElementByName`? because the textfields on this site (not google) haven't got an id

Comment: I have found the id for Google. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks but I mean generally if there is something like `javascript:document.getElementByName` because Google was just an EXAMPLE

Comment: It should have one (especially if the website uses javascript).